# Disable next years from the current year in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am working with the bootstrap. Here I have created input box for year.I want to display only year so I have write js like this :

```
$(".date").datetimepicker( {
        format: "Y",
});
```

So,its display only year.But I want to **disable** all **next years** from the current year.
So what option should I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the following after your code:

```
var maxDate = new Date("2016-12-31");
$('.date').datetimepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
```